# Svn reintegrate a branch in a new trunk-copied-branch

Tags: svn, merge, branch, svn-reintegrate

I have my project in which I have to reintegrate 2 branches in the trunk...the situation is this one:

```
                            trunk (r: xxx)
                              |
                              |---- created branch1 (r: xxx+1)
                              |      |
created branch2 (r: xxx+3)----|      |
 |                            |      |
 |                            |      |
 |                            |      |
 |                            |      |
```

Now I want to unify and reintegrate the two branches in a new one.

I have tried to create a new branch using:

`svn cp ^/trunk ^/branches/app-v2`

and then make a in the new branch:

`svn merge ^/branches/branch1 --reintegrate`

But I got:

`svn: '/svnrepos/!svn/bc/xxx/branches/app-v2' path not found`

I think that it depend that when the **branch1** was created the **app-v2** doesn't exist.

If I try with a regular merge (without `--reintegrate`) I have a lot of conflicts...

How can I merge the two branches in a new one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> How can I merge the two branches in a new one?

- Read SVN Book and `svn help merge` about all merge details
- **Never** try to "reintegrate" branch into non-parent - it's useless, not working idea and just wasted time
- Use correct part of repository as source for preliminary copy

or

- Perform 2-URL merge in empty new branch's WC (a lot of possible conflicts may be fair price, depending from stored changes in diverged histories)

Comment: The problem is that the trunk is still waiting for an approvation for my 1.0 release and I have the two branches ready with some functionalities of the 2.0 release...So the only solution is wait for the final 1.0 release and then reintegrate my branches..in the meantime I will synchronize my branches...It's not matter of homework but it's matter of what the client have in mind when ask you stuff :D

Comment: @rascio - merge two branches into independent 3-rd